# How to perform conditional search within a nested list

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a nested list as follows:

```
list(c("Oesophagus irregular z-line as previously.", " quad biopsies at ,,,m"
), c("Normal examination", "cardia mild inflammation."
), c("stomach normal", "Small polyp EMR and completely removed", 
"Duodenum  normal", "Jejunum normal", "GOJ normal", 
"Nodule seen at the mid oesophagus normal", "This was removed by EMR", 
"All other sites normal  normal", " A small area of residual stomach was removed by APC "))
```

I would like to search in each element for the presence of any term taken from a list called `EventList`:

```
EventList<-c("RFA","EMR","APC")
```

If the term is found then I would like to see if a location from a locaation list, is also present in the same sentence:

```
LocationList<-function(){

  tofind <-paste(c("Stomach","Antrum","Duodenum","Oesophagus","GOJ"),collapse = "|")

  return(tofind)

}
```

If it is not found then I'd like to look in the preceding sentence to see if a location can be seen.

So far I have been able to look in the same sentence only:

```
r1 <-lapply(text,function(x) Map(paste, str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(EventList)), str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(LocationList())), MoreArgs = list(sep=":")))
```

but this just looks for the presence of the terms in each sentence and outputs nothing if not present. How do I convert this to also look in the preceding sentence in a list? Someting like this:

```
ifelse(lapply(text,function(x) str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(LocationList())),str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(EventList()), lag element and do the same??
```

**Intended output:**

```
1 ""
2 ""
3 stomach:EMR,oesophagus:EMR,stomach:APC
```

Comment: Please check your functions.  It is giving some errors

Comment: Thanks @akrun I have corrected the typo in the EventList

Comment: Thanks, also a doubt, is that leading spaces intentional

Comment: Yes it is: to avoid the acronym being picked up as part of another word

Comment: Why EventList and LocationList are defined as functions, maybe just lists?

Comment: Based on the `text`, for the 3rd row, I get `stomach, dudoenum, goj,oesophagus`.  Please check `lapply(text, function(x) {x1 <- unique(unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(x), tolower(LocationList())))); x2 <-  unique(unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(x), tolower(paste(unlist(EventList()), collapse="|"))))); x1})`

Comment: @zx8754 I use them in several places in my package so seemed the easiest way

Comment: @akrun did you get that because it is just picking up the location? I would like to pick up the Event first and if present see if location is present in the same sentence and if not then see if location is present in the sentence above

Comment: @akrun Ive changed the EventList to a non-named list. So basically Im looking to run lapply(text,function(x) str_extract_all(x, EventList)) and if an event is found, then it looks in the sentence above to see if there is a location myl<-lapply(text,function(x) str_extract_all(x, LocationList())), and if so, then it adds the location to the Event. It is looking at the preceding line in a nested list that I am having difficulties with

Comment: I think you need to `paste` the 'Eventlist` similar to the 'LocationList`

Comment: Still I am not getting the last `stomach` May be I didn't get the logic correctly `lapply(text,function(x) {
         
     x1 <- str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(paste(EventList, collapse="|")))
     i1 <- which(lengths(x1) > 0)
     if(any(i1)) {
          paste(str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1 - 1]), tolower(LocationList())), toupper(x1[i1]), sep=":")
     
     } else ""
       }
    )`

Comment: @akrun The last stomach is because the location is located in the same sentence as the event. The idea is that once Event is found, to look in the same sentence and then in the one above

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Thanks, I posted modified comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conditions mentioned in the post

```
sapply(text,function(x) {

           x1 <- str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(paste(EventList, collapse="|")))
           i1 <- which(lengths(x1) > 0)
           if(any(i1)) {
             paste(unlist(Map(c, str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1-1]), 
                                         tolower(LocationList())), 
                       str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1]), tolower(LocationList())))), 
                        toupper(x1[i1]), sep=":", collapse=", ") 

           } else ""

             }

             )

#[1] ""  
#[2] ""   
#[3] "stomach:EMR, oesophagus:EMR, stomach:APC"
```

Comment: Hi @akrun. I get the error Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length which must be related to the line str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1-1]). I guess it is because in my larger dataset there are ?empty lines

Comment: @SebastianZek. Probabli=ty that would be the case.  You may need to add a `if/else` or `tryCatch` to keep it moving