# How to search previous strings in a list until match found

Tags: r

This question is derived from a previous question I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125654/how-to-perform-conditional-search-within-a-nested-list/54131982?noredirect=1#comment95099976_54131982) but I've changed the input list and the question is different:

In brief, I am trying to extract the presence of an 'event' from an event list and once detected, I am looking for the location of the event from a location list. I look first in the sentence that the event happened in and then in the previous sentence. I want to find the occurrence of the location that is the nearest written location (prior to the event in the text) in the raw report

The problem I have is that the location may be in a sentence that is two or three sentences previous to the sentence with the event in so I would like to detect these too.

**My input nested list is:**

```
list(c("Oesophagus irregular z-line as previously.", " quad biopsies at ,,,m"
), c("Normal examination", "cardia mild inflammation."
), c("stomach normal", "No problems here", 
"Everything  normal", "Small polyp EMR and completely removed", "GOJ normal", 
"Nodule seen which was normal", "This was removed by EMR", 
"All other sites normal  normal", " A small area of residual stomach was removed by APC "))
```

**The event list**

```
EventList<-c("RFA","EMR","APC")
```

**The location list**

```
LocationList<-function(){

  tofind <-paste(c("Stomach","Antrum","Duodenum","Oesophagus","GOJ"),collapse = "|")

  return(tofind)

}
```

**My desired output is:**

```
""  
""   
"stomach:EMR, goj:EMR, stomach:APC"
```

**Attempt 1**

@akrun very helpfully helped me to create the solution ( as long as only one previous sentence in the list of sentences is being searched for the location) as follows:

```
sapply(text,function(x) {

           x1 <- str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(paste(EventList, collapse="|")))
           i1 <- which(lengths(x1) > 0)
           if(any(i1)) {
             paste(unlist(Map(c, str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1-1]), 
                                         tolower(LocationList())), 
                       str_extract_all(tolower(x[i1]), tolower(LocationList())))), 
                        toupper(x1[i1]), sep=":", collapse=", ") 

           } else ""

             }

             )
```

It seems like I actually don't need to keep the input list as a nested list (and it is probably easier to keep it as a full text so I can use a regex on the whole thing for a positive lookbehind) and so the function above can be redefined (with the pseudocode for the part I am having trouble constructing)

```
sapply(text,function(x) {


text<-lapply(text,function(x) paste(x,collapse=";"))
text<-unlist(text)

               x1 <- str_extract_all(tolower(x),tolower(paste(EventList, collapse="|")))
               i1 <- which(lengths(x1) > 0)
               if(any(i1)) {


              #How to iterate through all the events found in the x1 and then search the nearest location (from the location list) behind this in each report?

} else ""

                 }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

tofind <-paste(c("Stomach", "Antrum", "Duodenum", "Oesophagus", "GOJ"),collapse = "|")

EventList<-c("RFA","EMR","APC")

words <-
  YOURS_LIST %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str_replace_na()%>%
  str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%
  str_split(' ') %>%
  `[[`(1)

EventList %>%
  map(
    ~words %>%
      str_which(paste0('^.*', .x)) %>%
      map_chr(
        ~words[1:.x] %>%
          str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%
          str_extract_all(regex(tofind, ignore_case = TRUE)) %>%
          `[[`(1) %.>%
          .[length(.)]
      ) %>%
      paste0(':', .x)
  ) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str_subset('.+:')
```

Comment: Hi @PawelChabros I get the error : Error: `.x` is not a vector (closure) in the EventList part and the words returns NA. Is it because some of my strings are empty maybe? If so, can this be accomodated?

Comment: It works perfectly on both of my computers. Did you assign your list to the variable `YOURS_LIST`?

Comment: OK @PawelChabros I got it to work. Thanks. I just had to add str_rename_na() just before str_c(collapse = ' ') %>%. Can you explain it especially the map ?

Comment: First map finds all positions for all `EventList` words. Then it cuts whole text from the beggining till that position, finds all words from `tofind` and takes the last one.